# How to fix my Double Sliding Patio Door that has a Giant Gap

Tags: gap, new-home, sliding-glass-door

I have a Newly Constructed home the builder is saying done. I’ve found many things and had them fix it before I move in. But the one thing they keep not fixing is the giant Gap at the bottom of my Dual Sliding door. At this point I just want it fixed but not sure how to fix it or how to describe what’s wrong.

How would I fix this and/or how would you suggest I got about fixing it? Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: Is that torn weatherstripping? Can you see anything from the outside?

Comment: Sliding doors do not provide a 100% seal.  That said, it does look like some weatherstriping may be missing.  The rectangular hole is a weep hole that allows any water that gathers in the channel to drain out.  If the door is closing against a fixed panel, there may be weatherstriping that is not continuing to the bottom of the panel.  That is why you see light.  Look at the panel as well as the door.

Comment: I don't think the weatherstripping is torn, I think it just doesn't go all the way down where it should.  Kinda looks like a poor design, if this is new construction.

Comment: Yeah I use to install doors and windows when I was younger. These are two sliding doors and there is no weatherstripping good enough to cover a hole I can put two fingers through easily. I suspect the door isn’t the right size or something so instead sitting lower and closer together it’s raised to the max or something.  I mean a toad the size of hand got through there. 